# Special chacters in postgresql table names

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a need to have "special characters" in a PostgreSQL table name that I am creating dynamically as needed.

```
create table if not exists a#_tablename column1 integer;
```

It will create the table if I surround the table name with quotes "" in the sql statement, but with no quotes will throw a syntax error.

```
create table if not exists "a#_tablename" column1 integer;
```

Strangely, it doesn't have a problem with the '_' symbol, just the '#'.  If I use a symbol that forces me to embed quotes, I will have to embed quotes in all future sql statements referencing this table, which I would like to avoid.  I am programing this in Python 3 using psycopg2.  Are there any options that will allow psycopg2/postgresql to create the table without quotes?   Googling found a 2005 bug report on this.

[https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20051125085730.271511125023@pgfoundry.org]

Is there a list of special characters allowed?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not a bug. Read this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: If you want use `#` you need use double quotes. Same if you want use UpperCases.  So if you want avoid double quotes replace # for a different character. maybe `4` is close enough

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I ended up using a '$' character.  I just needed a 27th symbol for a 3x3x3 matrix, 'a' thru 'z' with '$' as the last one.